# Desktop top is lower than it should be

Tags: 11.10, screen, lightdm

I have a very odd problem with Ubuntu 11.10. Here is a picture of it:[image: This *is* a maximized window]

The window in the picture is maximized, but for some odd reason it does not cover the entire desktop area. That area of the desktop the window does not cover is a dead area - I also can't drag desktop items to there, though I can drag not-maximized windows to that area.

Rebooting doesn't help. The problem started after I configured some windows partitions to automount on startup(though I don't see how that could cause the problem...)

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Idan, is this a default install? Was it like this out of the box, or have you tweaked anything (in CCSM, for example)? Also, what video card and drivers are you using (if you know). Thanks!

Comment: @JaysonRowe: Well, default install always freezed on me, so I used the alternate CD and set it to not update the software as part of the install(I updated it after it was installed).
I'm a Linux newbie, so I don't really know how to tweak with Linux configurations, but I did install some stuff with `apt-get` - vim-gtk,lyx,culmus,livetex,and git, and in the gui department gtk,gtk-pixbuf and tint2, which I tweaked a bit with tintwizard.  
  
My graphics card is GForce GT 335M, and I installed the nvidia unix driver after the default driver alwayz made my Ubuntu freeze after 10 minutes.

Comment: Ok, none of that seems dangerous. I was just making sure you hadn't tweaked any Compiz settings. Can you select a "Unity 2D" session on the login screen to see if it happens with the Compiz (the 3D desktop rendering engine) disabled?

Comment: Also, did this only happen after selecting the Nvidia drivers? Did it ever work w/ the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @Jayson: You are my savior - switching to 2D fixed the problem! It also solved [my other problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78373/double-set-of-indicators-in-the-top-panel).
MMMmmm... since the problem is the desktop manager, and unity2D is not as good in functionality as regular unity(workspaces in row instead of circles, can't switching between windows of the same programs with `Alt+Tab` or with tint2, and that's just what I noticed in the 5 minutes since I logged in with 2D), I might just switch to GNOME Shell...
Anyways, please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Jayson: and as for your question - it worked for a whole day with the NVidia drivers.

Comment: Update: yup, GNOME Shell is much better than Unity!

Comment: Glad you got a solution that worked for you Idan, but it didn't really resolve the issue. I'd rather not post my response as an answer since I was just going through troubleshooting steps. Someone else may have the same issue. Could you possibly file your question as a bug report in Launchpad?

Comment: @Jayson: Well, I just logged in with unity, and the problem does not appear anymore, so `ubuntu-bug` can no longer collect the information to send...

Comment: that is very odd - perhaps logging into a different environment reset some config? I wish I had an explanation, but I'm very happy it's working for you now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll speculate that this was caused by a [window manager strut](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2507618) reserving space at the top edge of the screen:

> The purpose of struts is to reserve space at the borders of the
>   desktop. This is very useful for a docking area, a taskbar or a panel,
>   for instance. The Window Manager should take this reserved area into
>   account when constraining window positions - maximized windows, for
>   example, should not cover that area.

tint2, which you mentioned having installed, will do precisely this in accordance with its [panel geometry and `strut_policy`](http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Configure#Panel) configuration options.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't bother me anymore, since I moved to GNOME Shell